# How to generate a time-stamp for HTTP-Header If-Modified-Since from QDateTime?

Tags: c++, qt, http-headers, timezone

I want to set an If-Modified-Since-header on a request and take the time from the timestamp on the file. So I extracted the timestamp into a QDateTime. I could generate something looking similar to the date-format HTTP uses, but my server and my client use different time-zones. Is there a way to get the timezone-string from Qt or another way to generate the string for the header. Here my code so far:

```
QLocale locale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
QString modificationDate = locale.toString(fileinfo.lastModified(), "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'");
```

I have to set the locale, because the system-locale is different and the server doesn't understand the format generated that way. It would be helpful, if I could get the timezone from Qt, so that I could add that to the String instead of the constant 'GMT'. But I didn't found a way to get the timezone Qt is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
QString modificationDate = fileinfo.lastModified().toUTC().toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " GMT";
```

Comment: I need the Locale-stuff, because with my german locale it starts with 'Di' instead of 'Tue' and the server doesn't understand this. But your hint to toUTC() is helpful, this corrects the differences in the timezones. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the localized day of week names. Didn't know QDateTime uses system locale for that.

Comment: needs a space before GMT

Answer (score 0):

Here is an slightly more elegant solution, which is used by Qt internally:

```
QByteArray QNetworkHeadersPrivate::toHttpDate(const QDateTime &dt)
{
    return QLocale::c().toString(dt, QLatin1String("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'"))
        .toLatin1();
}
```